# Newbie to Linux-which one to choose for hp stream

Tags: hp, stream

I'm completely new to Linux and not very tech savvy. I have a HP 14" stream laptop with these specs:

[image: my specs]

I just want the laptop for internet browsing.

I have heard of some problems with wifi and trackpad and was wondering if I need a previous version of Linux?

Should I try the Lite version or the standard?

Also I will be removing win 10 completely from my laptop.  Do I just follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your specs you can handle the regular version of ubuntu, but you shouldn't have any driver issues no matter what flavour (more on that later) you choose.

Which version (aka flavour) of ubuntu should you install? Well that depends on your preferences, specifically it depends on what desktop environment you find suits your needs best. What am I talking about? Windows always comes with a panel at the bottom, macOS with a top panel and a dock; linux users instead choose which layout they prefer between the many available, to start I suggest you take a look at images of ubuntu and it's flavours on google and see which one you find more comfortable (I'd suggest checking out ubuntu, kubuntu, xubuntu and ubuntu budgie).

Once you've decided download the iso from the official site ([example](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) for regular ubuntu), the installation is then very simple. On windows:
 download [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/?locale), 
insert a usb stick (2GB at least), fire up rufus and click on the CD next to the box with FREEDOS written in it to choose the .iso file you downloaded. Click start and wait.

Once it's finished reboot your PC. You then have to enter the boot menu, on my PC I have to press f11 when the motherboard screen comes up, but the key is different on each PC. Once you've managed that select the usb stick from the menu, you'll then be able to choose to be sent to the "live" version of ubuntu (basically you can play around without installing it, useful if you want to test various flavours) or install ubuntu (or whatever flavour you chose) directly. From there the process on screen is pretty straightforward (in your case choose the option to replace windows when prompted).

Comment: Great and thank you so much for the very helpful answer, exactly what I was looking for.  I apologise to those who commented for the vagueness of my question.  I will try to improve on this but at this stage, my understanding of all of this type of thing is really zero.  So I don't want to sound as if I know a little when I don't.